# React useQuery causes many rerenders before and after the data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have this simple app where makes a call to an API. I am using react-query to make the fetch and also to cache the data. However, even though the function is wrapped in `React.memo`, `useQuery` causes multiple re-renders for no reason. It should be 2 renderings not 8.

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import Axios from "axios";

const fetchTodoList = async (key, id) => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`
  );
  return data;
};

function App() {
  const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery("todos", fetchTodoList);
  console.log(isLoading, data);
  if (isLoading) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>;
  }

  // also status === 'success', but "else" logic works, too
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((todo) => (
        <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default memo(App);
```

Comment: Memo is about returning the same component for a given props. Ur app component is not taking any props. And ur rerenders are happening cause the variables u destructure from react query are getting different values hence a rerender. Every variable has 2 states which can cause a rerender. There is nothing wrong with ur code afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Memo is designed to prevent re-renders due to the parent changing, not from the component itself changing.  From the `memo` [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo):

> Even with memo, your component will re-render if its own state changes

In terms of why the state of the component itself is changing: useQuery is tracking a BUNCH of state variables!  You can see a list in the [docs](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/reference/useQuery):

> data,
> dataUpdatedAt,
> error,
> errorUpdatedAt,
> failureCount,
> failureReason,
> fetchStatus,
> isError,
> isFetched,
> isFetchedAfterMount,
> isFetching,
> isInitialLoading,
> isLoading,
> isLoadingError,
> isPaused,
> isPending,
> isPlaceholderData,
> isRefetchError,
> isRefetching,
> isStale,
> isSuccess,
> refetch,
> status,

Whenever any of those changes, React Query needs to update the state in order to make sure that your application can respond to those changes.  In other words, when staleness changes, when it gets garbage collected, when the network starts fetching, etc, should all trigger a re-render.  I suspect if you logged the full return from useQuery, you would see at least one value different in each re-render.